# cannot insert duplicate key row in object dbo.msmerge_tombstone with unique index 'uc1MSmerge_tombstone

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication, database-replication, merge-replication

I have a merge replication setup in a server.I took the backup of subscriber database and restored it in another server with keep replication on(i restored it in entire different server where no replication is setup).

When i try inserting bulk data to this restored database i am getting error like

> cannot insert duplicate key row in object dbo.msmerge_tombstone with
>   unique index 'uc1MSmerge_tombstone'.the duplicate key value is
>   (3674005,67607BE2-A12C-E211-8F84-3860777B763D).The statement has been
>   terminated.

Why this error comes? How i can solve this?